# How could I make a ES6 Class method execute some some default behaviour when a subclass function is called, without using the super constructor?

Tags: javascript, oop, ecmascript-6, es6-class

So trying to build some js classes I've run into some knowledge gap as this is my first time implementing OOP and ES6 constructors.

I basically have an application that runs a `respond()` method that I need to have some default behavior to be performed from its parent class when executed at an `"Emergency Event"`.

In this illustration, all subclasses derived from `NuclearStrategy` should always `Appease the population` no matter what's declared in the `Action` subclass `respondToThreat()` method for example. And if `eventIsJustTest === true` then nothing else should be done other than `Appease the population`.

So this is what I'm implementing:

```js
class NuclearStrategy {
  constructor(props) {
    this.eventOrigin = props.eventOrigin;
  }

  appeaseAllPopulation() {
    console.log('✅ Appeasing the population');
  }

  respondToThreat({ eventIsJustTest }) {
    this.appeaseAllPopulation();
    if (eventIsJustTest) return;                            // I expect this to exit the function and ignore anything declared after <super.respondToThreat()>
  }
}


class Action extends NuclearStrategy {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  respondToThreat(responseArgs) {
    super.respondToThreat(responseArgs.eventIsJustTest);   // <- I can't have this in my code
    console.log(`✅ Playing alert siren`);                 // <- This shouldn't be executed
    console.log(`✅ Launched ICBM nuke to enemy`)          // <- Avoid also
  }
}


new Action({ eventOrigin: 'East Qorea' }).respondToThreat({ eventIsJustTest: true });
```

This executes

```js
✅ Appeasing the population
✅ Playing alert siren
✅ Launched ICBM nuke to enemy
```

Should only execute

```js
✅ Appeasing the population
```

With this, I'm failing to stop a nuke launching with `Action.respondToThreat` even when the alert was just for a `nuclear test` (RIP Earth). Also, I can't have any `super` call at my subclass `super.respondToThreat()`, the `appeaseAllPopulation()` behavior should be executed by default ***without ever calling it***.

Would you have any advice on this application?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not just leave `respondToThreat` method out of `Action` class, as it seems to contain only some undesirable content.

Comment: "*the `appeaseAllPopulation()` behavior should be executed by default without ever calling it*" - this is not possible if you are not controlling the subclass. Although it's really not clear why or how you are unable to put some restrictions/contracts on subclasses and their method implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution would be to not override `respondToThreat` at all and instead call a method/hook that should be implemented by the child classes.

```js
class NuclearStrategy {
  constructor(props) {
    this.eventOrigin = props.eventOrigin;
  }

  appeaseAllPopulation() {
    console.log('Broadcasting ');
  }

  respondToThreat({ eventIsJustTest }) {
    console.log(`✅ Appeasing the population`);
    if (eventIsJustTest) return;
    this.respondToNonTestThreat();
  }
  
  respondToNonTestThreat() {} // default implementation do nothing
}

class Action extends NuclearStrategy {
  respondToNonTestThreat() {
    console.log(`✅ Playing alert siren`);
    console.log(`✅ Launched ICBM nuke to enemy`);
  }
}

const action = new Action({ eventOrigin: 'East Qorea' });

console.log("test threat:");
action.respondToThreat({ eventIsJustTest: true });
console.log("non-test threat:");
action.respondToThreat({});
```

Comment: This is a much better design, but doesn't stop the subclass from overwriting `respondToThreat` with a method that doesn't appease the population. (Which, admittedly, is pretty impossible).

Comment: That's true, if you don't want a sub-class to override specific methods you should not sub-class at all. [I've added another answer that doesn't allow overriding.](/a/64977996/3982562) This basically works by passing a bunch of callbacks to execute at given times.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent the programmer from overriding important methods, instead of sub-classing you could pass only the logic to execute. In this scenario the class invoking the logic should document what logic is executed in what scenario. What the passed parameters are and what the expected return value should be.

The above can be done in a lot of different ways, here is an example:

```js
class Hooks {
  constructor(hooks, context) {
    this.hooks   = hooks;
    this.context = context;
  }
  
  find(...path) {
    let cursor = this.hooks;
    for (const key of path) {
      if (!cursor[key]) return this.noop;
      cursor = cursor[key];
    }
    return cursor.bind(this.context);
  }
  
  noop() {}
}

class NuclearStrategy {
  static withPresetHooks(hooks) {
    return (props) => new this({ ...props, hooks });
  }

  constructor(props) {
    this.eventOrigin = props.eventOrigin;
    this.hooks       = new Hooks(props.hooks || {}, this);
  }

  appeaseAllPopulation() {
    console.log('Broadcasting ');
  }

  respondToThreat({ eventIsJustTest }) {
    console.log(`✅ Appeasing the population`);
    this.hooks.find("respondToThreat", "eventIsJustTest", !!eventIsJustTest)();
  }
}

const createAction = NuclearStrategy.withPresetHooks({
  respondToThreat: {
    eventIsJustTest: {
      true: function () {
        console.log(`✅ Testing alert siren`);
      },
      false: function () {
        console.log(`✅ Playing alert siren`);
        console.log(`✅ Launched ICBM nuke to enemy`);
      },
    },
  },
});

const action = createAction({ eventOrigin: 'East Qorea' });

console.log("test threat:");
action.respondToThreat({ eventIsJustTest: true });
console.log("non-test threat:");
action.respondToThreat({});
```